# cakephp set::extract

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I know that set:extract can get one item from an array like this

Set::extract('/myArray/item',$items);

but what if I need multiple items? with id, i need name too.

Comment: Post your array and your desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get multiple items using `Set::extract` but it depends on the structure of your array and what you want to extract from that array.

For example let's say we have something like...

- [Fruits]

  - [Apples]

    - [Washington]
    - [Sour]
  - [Oranges]
  - [Grapes]

To select all children of fruit you'd enter `Fruit`.  To get specific types of Apples you'd do `/Fruits/Apple`.  There are a lot of other things that you can do as well.  Go to [XPath Syntax](http://bit.ly/mkAZii) for more information.  Hope this helps.

Comment: yes but how would you get WASHINGTON and SOUR together in one array

Comment: The `/Fruits/Apples` will give you both.

Answer (score 0):

Felix Geisendörfer from Debuggable has some really excellent examples of how to utilize Set::extract to get multiple values from various nested data structures

http://debuggable.com/posts/cake-12s-set-class-eats-arrays-for-breakfast:480f4dd6-d084-4fb7-bacc-49fdcbdd56cb

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: Take a look at the sources ($CAKE_DIR/libs/set.php or [online](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.2/cake/libs/set.php) and in $CAKE_DIR/tests/cases/libs/set.test.php or [online](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.2/cake/tests/cases/libs/set.test.php)): you'll find some usage examples (this is true at least for cakephp 1.2.x).